# Condition if else shows me the results backwards. What's going on?

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I have made a simple if else condition where it should show which is the greater number of the two inputs entered, but it shows me the opposite value than expected. What's going on? Thanks in advance!

HTML:

```
 <input type= "text" id="texto">
 <input type= "text" id="texto2">
 <button type="submit" id="enviar">Enviar</button>
```

JS:

```
const texto = document.getElementById('texto');
const texto2 = document.getElementById('texto2');
const send = document.getElementById('send');
send.addEventListener('click', mayorque)


function mayorque() {

if (texto > texto2){
    
    alert('Input 1 is greater than input 2')
} else {
    alert('Input 2 is greater than input 1')
}

    
}
```

Comment: `texto` and `texto2` are simply HTML elements - it doesn't really make sense to compare them. You don't show us your HTML, but assuming those are input elements, you can get the actual value the user has entered by reading their `.value` property. (But you'll also want to convert the values to numbers - they'll be strings by default - so numeric comparison works as you presumably intend.)

Comment: I had tried with .value too but it gave me the same problem... I attach the HTML, which I had forgotten!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few problems.

When you set the variable **texto** on load, it is grabbing the value of the input on load. You will need to get the value in the function.

Using something like **parseFloat** will convert the value to a numeric value. Float will allow for decimal points.

```js
let texto = document.getElementById('texto');
let texto2 = document.getElementById('texto2');
const send = document.getElementById('send');
send.addEventListener('click', mayorque)


function mayorque() {
  texto = parseFloat(texto.value);
  texto2 = parseFloat(texto2.value);
  if (texto > texto2) {

    alert('Input 1 is greater than input 2')
  } else {
    alert('Input 2 is greater than input 1')
  }


}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="texto">
<input type="text" id="texto2">
<button type="submit" id="send">Enviar</button>
```